# why does my output signal have 2 clock cycles delay?

Tags: verilog

For each bit in a 32-bit vector, capture when the input signal changes from 1 in one clock cycle to 0 the next. "Capture" means that the output will remain 1 until the register is reset (synchronous reset).
Each output bit behaves like a SR flip-flop: The output bit should be set (to 1) the cycle after a 1 to 0 transition occurs. The output bit should be reset (to 0) at the positive clock edge when reset is high. If both of the above events occur at the same time, reset has precedence. In the last 4 cycles of the example waveform below, the 'reset' event occurs one cycle earlier than the 'set' event, so there is no conflict here.
In the example waveform below, reset, in[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekXTP.png) and out[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekXTP.png) are shown again separately for clarity.

[image]

my code:

```
module top_module (
  input clk,
  input reset,
  input [31:0] in,
  output [31:0] out );
  integer i;
  reg [31:0] in_del;
  reg [31:0] out_del;
  always @ (posedge clk)
      begin
          in_del<=in;
          out_del<=~in & in_del;
          if (reset)
              out=0;
          else
              begin
                  for (i=0; i<32;i=i+1) begin
                      if (out_del[i])
                          out[i]=out_del[i];
                  end

              end
      end
endmodule
```

my output

[image]

Comment: `in_del` and `out_del` are registers assigned-to in an `always @ posedge` block, so they will each encounter one clock cycle of delay. You could consider using the blocking assignment statement `out_del = ~in & in_del` instead and it *might* work

Comment: Are you aware that this code cannot be synthesized, contains semantic errors (cannot be compiled) and violates industry practice for use of blocking/non-blocking assignments? What is the purpose of it?

Answer (score 1):

First about your code.

1. it cannot be compiled. The `out` must be a `reg` in order to be assignable within the `always` block.
2. using non-blocking assignment in `out_del <= in & in_del` will cause a one-cycle delay for the `if (out_del)` comparison. Non-blocking assignments schedule lhs assignment after the block gets evaluated. The rule of thumb is to always use **blocking** assignments for **intermediate** signals in the sequential block.
3. because of the above and because of the `in & in_del`, this cannot be synthesized, or at least it cannot be synthesized correctly.
4. you violate industry practices by using the `blocking` assignment on the `out` signal. The rule of thumb is to always use **non-blocking** assignments for the **outputs** of the sequential blocks.
5. the code just does not work :-(

If I understood your requirement correctly the following code does it:

```
module top_module (
  input clk,
  input reset,
  input [31:0] in,
  output reg [31:0] out );
  reg lock;
  always @ (posedge clk)
      begin
        if (reset) begin
              lock <= 0;
              out <= 0;
          end
          else if (lock == 0)
              begin
                out <= in;
                lock <= 1;
              end
      end
endmodule
```

Just use the `lock` signal to allow updated. And yes, here is a simple test bench to check it:

```
module real_top();

    reg clk, reset;
    reg [31:0] in;
    reg [31:0] out;

    top_module tm(clk, reset, in, out);

    initial begin
        clk = 0;
        forever #5 clk = ~clk;
    end

    integer i;
    initial begin 
      in = 0;
      reset = 1;
      #7 reset = 0;
      for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) begin
        #10 in = i;
        #10 reset = 1;
        #10 reset = 0;
      end
      $finish;
    end

    initial 
      $monitor(clk, reset, in, out);
endmodule
```